# How to safely force unwrap time in dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, swiftlint, forceunwrap

I have an issue. I have a dictionary type [String: Any]

my code that works is

```
dict["start"] = "\(start.hour!):\(start.minute!)"
if let end = end {
    dict["end"] = "\(end.hour!):\(end.minute!)"
}
```

But as I use swiftlint it throws me an error for force unwrapping. Value must be saved so if let is not good here :)

Comment: What type variables start and end has?

Comment: No, String doesn't have properties hour and minute. Is it a type you have created yourself or from a framework or similar?

Comment: ah sorry. Its DateComponents

Comment: If you have specified both `hour` and `minute` in `DateComponents` force unwrapping is 1000% safe. SwiftLint is nitpicking.

Comment: so I should just add a swiftlint ignore and move on ? :) well, thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it's really nonhazardous to do that.

Comment: This is why I will never use linters. There are plenty of situations where force-unwrapping a variable is perfectly safe, and SwiftLint (or any linter, for that matter) will never be smart enough to pick up on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is mostly a semantic issue, but you could do something like this:

```
if let startHour = start.hour,
   let startMinute = start.minute {

    dict["start"] = "\(startHour):\(startMinute)"

    if let end = end,
       let endHour = end.hour,
       let endMinute = end.minute {

       dict["end"] = "\(endHour):\(endMinute)"
    }
}
```

...or something similar – as there are various ways in Swift to safely unwrap an optional.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following demo code. I hope it will help you.

```
import Foundation

let calendar = Calendar.current

let dateComponents = DateComponents(hour: 12, minute: 20, second: 55)

func getHoursMinutesFrom(time: DateComponents) -> (hour: Int,minute: Int) {
    switch (time.hour, time.minute) {
    case let (.some(hour), .some(minutes)):
        return (hour,minutes)
    default:
        return (0,0)
    }
}

print(getHoursMinutesFrom(time: dateComponents))
```

Comment: this dosn't help a lot becouse this doesn't use dicts, but thanks anyway ;)